# mysql replaces php openssl encrypted text with question marks

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I am developing a messaging app, the only 2 way encryption php method I found is `openssl_encrypt()`, I successfully encrypt it, but when I insert it into the database, all characters are replaced with question marks, I have changed the collation of the table and the column, I have tried half the collations with no luck, I did some research, and I found out that there were slovak, vietnamese, and characters from another language along with copyright and trademark icons in the `openssl_encrypt()` encrypted text. what character encoding am I supposed to use ?

Comment: Don't use a text column type at all, use a binary one. Eg: `BINARY`, `VARBINARY`, or a `BLOB` type.

Comment: Got some code? Schema for your table? What encoding does the table use? Need the info to answer... [Throw me a frickin bone here...](https://youtu.be/E7Eso6d9vik?t=45)

Comment: as i said, i have tried half the different encodings in mysql, i think the problem is that the encrypted text has characters from two different encodings, for example the encryption of the string "hello" has slovak, vietnamese characters along with the copyright and registered trademark characters.